# ruby on rails create new entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, methods

I have a Web App that I developed using Ruby on Rails and all my CRUD actions are working just fine. When I create a new project, a new form is displayed and I can fill in all the fields for the new project.

Since there are so many fields that are identical for multiple projects, I'd like to add an action like "duplicate" so that I can create a new project from an existing one, that would have all form entries the same, then I'll have only minor changes to make into the new project and update it in the database.

These are my actions

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

# GET /projects/1
# GET /projects.1.json
def index
  @projects = Project.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render :json => @projects }
  end
end

# GET /projects/1
# GET /projects/1.json
def show
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render :json => @project }
  end
end

# GET /projects/new
# GET /projects/new.json
def new
  @project = Project.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render :json => @project }
  end
end

# GET /projects/1/edit
def edit
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
end

# POST /projects
# POST /projects.json
def create
  @project = Project.new(params[:project])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @project.save
    format.html { redirect_to @project, :notice => 'Project was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :json => @project, :status => :created, :location => @project }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.json { render :json => @project.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# POST /projects/1
# PUT /projects/1.json
def update
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @project.update_attributes(params[:project])
      format.html { redirect_to @project, :notice => 'Project was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :ok }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "edit" }
      format.json { render :json => @project.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# DELETE /projects/1
# DELETE /projects/1.json
def destroy
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  @project.destroy

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to projects_url }
    format.json { head :ok }
  end
end
end
```

How would my "duplicate" or "copy" action look like in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
def duplicate
  old_project = Project.find(params[:id])
  attributes = old_project.attributes.except(:id, :created_at, :updated_at)
  @project = Project.new(attributes)
  render :new
end
```

Or maybe:

```
def duplicate
  old_project = Project.find(params[:id])
  attributes = old_project.attributes.except(:id, :created_at, :updated_at)
  @project = Project.new(attributes)
  if @project.save
    redirect_to project_path
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

Note that in if you are using `strong_params` you might have to assign the params individually to prevent a forbidden attributes error.

As pointed out in the comments, you

Comment: wow. Do you plan to copy even `id`, `created_at`, `updated_at` fields? It's impossible to answer without knowing `Project` model validations/uniq indexes.

Answer (score 2):

I would try something like this:

```
# in the routes.rb
resources :projects do
  get 'dublicate', :on => :member
end
```

That allow you to build links to the dublicate action like in the views like this: `link_to('duplicate', dublicate_project_path(@project))`

```
# in the controller
def dublicate
  existing = Project.find(params[:id])
  @project = existing.dup

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :new } 
    format.json { render :json => @project }
  end
end
```

That would duplicate (see: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Core/dup) the attributes of the existing project (without the id field) into an new project and than show the new page with prepopuated fields.

Comment: How is this different than my answer? I suggested using `model.attribtues`.

Comment: Changed my answer to `dup`. Seems to be more appropriate. Btw. I did not copy your answer, like you indicated. We both answered almost at the same time.

Comment: Thanks @spickermann. I tried this ans it's throwing this error "private method `initialize_dup' called for #<Project:0x007f895b68f880>"

Comment: Surprising, because `initialize_dup` is public, not private (see: http://apidock.com/rails/v4.1.8/ActiveRecord/Core/initialize_dup). What Rails version do you use?

Comment: I'm using Rails 3.1.0

Comment: `dup` is actually a better solution since it does not copy the id and timestamps. +1. But it may not be working because of the Rails version. I would try with `clone`. `dup` is Rails 3.1+ (I think).

Comment: @spickermann : thank you for your answer. My server is throwing a syntax error because of this line "get 'dublicate', on: :member" /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load': /home/user/apps/config/routes.rb:15: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting kEND (SyntaxError)

Comment: @rh4games: I updated my answer. It was using Ruby 1.9 syntax. I did not notice that you are still on Ruby 1.8.